# Order by views limiting, then order by another column

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, sql-order-by, limit

I have a query that selects * from my database ordering by views and limiting by 4:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE visible = 1 ORDER BY views LIMIT 4;
```

But in the same query I want to find all other rows ordering by column updated_at.

I haved tryied things like this, but doesn't works:

```
(SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 4)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY updated_at DESC);
```

The propose this are "pinning" the 4 hotest articles on home page and then ordering by time was updated.

Have any way to ORDER BY multiple ways in the same query without repeat the rows?

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want the hottest 4 _first_ in the list?  How many articles are shown on the home page?  If there are more articles than will fit, then how many?  (Please edit the question to be more precise.  Then maybe I will provide an answer better than Tim's.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html):

> ... The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result. ...

And

> ... If ORDER BY appears without LIMIT in a SELECT, it is optimized away because it will have no effect anyway. ...

So the trick here is to use `limit` in the second query (it is up to you to choose the limit):

```
(SELECT * FROM articles WHERE visible = 1 ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 4)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM articles WHERE visible = 1 ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 100);
```

The query was tested in MySQL 5.6 and 5.7.

Comment: This really worked perfectly! Thanks for the insight, helped me to solve the problem!

Comment: The problem with this query is that it has no ordering.  There is no guarantee that the first four greatest views will appear first in the result set.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen please provide more evidence about your statement.

Comment: There is no automatic order in a SQL query, as tables are modeled after unordered sets.  If your answer appears to work now, there is no guarantee that the ordering will persist in the future.  You absolutely need to have an `ORDER BY` clause to make sure the 4 most popular articles appear first.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I can't argue about the future and don't want to debate, but if you provide the dataset, which breaks the query using existing version of MySQL or MariaDB, this will be very beneficial for all of us.

Comment: @zstate [This demo](http://rextester.com/EON68581) is the best I could seem to do in MySQL to show that your query won't work.  If you switch the order of the union, the result you get is completely unordered.  It appears that MySQL appears to maintain the order as you have phrased your query, but again we definitely should not be relying on this.

Comment: @zstate [Here is a demo in Postgres](http://rextester.com/ZDRM58445) using your same exact query.  You will clearly see that the order of the result set is totally random.  Again, MySQL appears to be giving the correct order, but beware because if the data changes, or the version changes, the ordering could easily be broken.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You MySQL demo completely makes sense. You would get 10 rows ordered by `updated_at `, since as I mentioned in my answer MySQL `union` removes duplicate rows, so there is nothing to fetch for the second query.

Comment: @zstate And what about the Postgres query?  At the very least, you should edit your answer and state that your query is only guaranteed to work correctly with MySQL extensions.  Ideally, you should cite the documentation which supports this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you for providing PostgreSQL example. You are right PostgreSQL completely ignores `order by` in the union queries, which MySQL is not and I thought the questions is tagged with MySQL and MariaDB.

Comment: Postgres _does not_ ignore `ORDER BY` in union queries.  The result is due to that the overall query has no ordering, like your answer, as I have said already too many times.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing with your current thinking, we can take a union of two subqueries.  The first subquery is what you already included in your question, and finds the 4 more frequently viewed articles.  The second subquery finds everything else.  The trick here is to include in each subquery a computed field which we can use to keep track of the top 4 records from everything else.  Then, we order by this computed field first, followed second by the `updated_at` field.

```
(
    SELECT a.*, 1 AS label
    FROM articles a
    WHERE visible = 1
    ORDER BY views DESC
    LIMIT 4
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT a.*, 2
    FROM articles a
    WHERE visible = 1
    ORDER BY views DESC
    LIMIT 1000000 OFFSET 4    -- the limit 1000000 is arbitrary; just use a number
)                              -- larger than the expected size of your table
ORDER BY
    label, views, updated_at
```

Comment: Should be `ORDER BY views DESC` right because @char4 wants the "hotest"  articles..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Right you are...the price I pay for mindlessly copying the query from the OP.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you, you're helping me a lot. I removed the comma before OFFSET and tried to run the query. Now I just had syntax errors: `(...) syntax to use near '1 AS label FROM articles a WHERE visible = 1 ORDER BY views DESC ' at line 2`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen In the second query you are missing `a` alias. It should be  `FROM articles a`. Even though the first query returns 4 top views, the entire result set will be ordered by `updated_at`, which is not exactly what was asked.

Comment: You're right about the missing alias, but wrong about the ordering.  The ordering uses the label, _followed by_ `updated_at`.  This is precisely what was asked.

Comment: If I understood correctly, It was asked to get top 4 rows `ORDER BY views` and then `ORDER BY updated_at`. Your query returns 4 top views rows, but they ordered by  `updated_at`. See the screenshot to understand what I mean [screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/OJ0tQi9d) .

Comment: @zstate I was in error.  I should have been using `ORDER BY label, views, updated_at`.  Thanks for pointing this and other typos out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comma to separate multiple `ORDER`commands.
MySQL will order from left to right.

`SELECT * FROM articles WHERE visible = 1 ORDER BY views, updated_at DESC LIMIT 4;`

Comment: But the result doesn't will be limited by 4?

I want find 4 hotest articles by `views` and then find all the rest rows ordering by `updated_at`.